# Can't find element on page no matter what I try

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am striking out on locating an element on a search results page.  I have tried locating by xpath, wait_for_element_to_be_clickable, find_element_by_link_text etc. and still can't get selenium to locate it.

If I have the driver reload the initial URL for the search page the same search results show up and not the initial search page.  I've tried nuking cookies etc.  This behavior exists on chrome and firefox.

Initial URL: https://elibrary.ferc.gov/eLibrary/search

just hitting the search button yields results.  However I can't locate the link "General Search" at the top of the page with selenium to go back and enter new search criteria.  The link is the same as the initial URL.  My code to select the link and click:

```
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="srchResult"]/nav/div/ul/li[1]/a[1]').click
            
        except:
            _LOGGER.warning('Could Not Click on General Search - starting new driver')
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"/usr/local/bin/geckodriver", options=options)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath for that link is: `//a[@aria-label='Return to General Search']`

Comment: OK so I can learn from this: how did you identify the correct xpath?  I inspected the element then copied the xpath in chrome

Comment: You should always look for unique locators. Here I found 'a' tag with area-label attribute,  which is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the element you are looking for with the following `xpath`:
`//a[contains(@aria-label,'Return to General Search')]`
or `xss_selector`: `a[aria-label='Return to General Search']`
Don't forget to put wait condition before clicking on it!

Answer (score 0):

That link is

```
<a _ngcontent-c1="" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Return to General Search" class="btn btn-link nav2" name="Refine" href="/eLibrary/search">General Search</a>
```

It has a name, which would be the preferred way to find it because it's least likely to change. The CSS selector below works.

```
a[name='Refine']
```